# Tuleap compatilibity with openfire 3.7 or newer

Tags: security, compatibility, instant-messaging, tuleap

I have a tuleap 8.10 server with openfire 3.6.4. After running a vulnerability analysis, I have the following message:

> **9090/tcp**
>
> 51143 - Openfire Admin Console login.jsp XSS
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> A web application on the remote host has a cross-site scripting vulnerability.
>
> **Description**
>
> The Openfire admin console running on the remote host has a cross-site scripting vulnerability. Input to the 'username' parameter of 'login.jsp' is not properly sanitized.
>
> An attacker could exploit this by tricking a user into making a specially crafted POST request, resulting in arbitrary script execution in the user's browser.
>
> This version of Openfire likely has other vulnerabilities, though Nessus has not checked for those issues.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Upgrade to Openfire 3.7.0 beta or later.
>
> **Risk Factor**
>
> Medium

I have seen in the commits of Tuleap that in 2012, a change has been made to use openfire 3.6.4 instead of 3.7.1.

Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to install openfire 3.7 or later with Tuleap ? (compatibility with the tuleap-plugin-openfire-3.6.4 ?)
2. Why the 3.7.1 of openfire has been dropped ?
3. Is there any will to upgrade the openfire version used by Tuleap for the next releases ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are aware of this issue and we have done some preliminary work to move to the latest version of Openfire (you can see https://gerrit.tuleap.net/#/c/4139/ for example).

We currently cannot move further due to a major bug in Openfire (see https://igniterealtime.org/issues/browse/OF-814) which could break existing Tuleap instances. As soon as this bug is resolved on the Openfire side we will upgrade.

Note that, to mitigate the risk, Openfire is no more installed by default on new installations and can not be installed easily by hand.